# Is there any trick that allows to use Management Studio's (ver. 2008) IntelliSense feature with earlier versions of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, intellisense

Latest version of Management Studio (i.e. the one that ships with SQL Server 2008) finally has a Transact-SQL IntelliSense feature. However, out-of-the-box it only works with SQL Server 2008 instances.

Is there some workaround for this?

*[I asked this question a while ago at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4511/95) and unfortunately nobody knew such a trick. Maybe I will have more luck with this problem here.]*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aside from using a third party tool, no. I run into this problem a lot too. The deal is the SqlServer2005 doesn't support the meta data to do that.

However, I can suggest (cos I used it for a bit and loved it) RedGates [SqlPrompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) product to do this. It's incredibly handy. However, it does cost money, so there's a tradeoff.

If someone DOES have a workaround for this, I would love to hear of it.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no workaround to make it work.  It looks at the version of the remote server which can't be faked.  SQL Prompt would be your best bet, that or upgrading to SQL Server 2008 or higher.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using from time to time the [SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/). It has a free version. It's a newcomer, from what I know. I've also liked the SQLPrompt too, in the past, but it's not free.
So give them a try.